# There is a natural number, whose every divisor is smaller than 147. How to write formally?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

I have a statement *There is a natural number, whose every divisor is smaller than 147.* and cannot figure out, which of the following options is correct (it can be more of them)

a.) $(∃x∈N)(∃n∈N)(∃k∈N)((x=n⋅k) ∧ (n<147))$

b.) $(∃x∈N)(∀n∈N)(∀k∈N)((x=n⋅k) ∨ (n<147))$

c.) $(∃x∈N)(∀n∈N)(∀k∈N)(x=n⋅k ⇒ n<147)$

d.) $(∃x∈N)(∃n∈N)(∀k∈N)(x=n⋅k ⇒n <147)$

Comment: The answer is c) because 'there is a natural number' = '$\exists x$', 'whose every divider' = '$\forall k,n\in\mathbb{N}, x=kn$' is smaller than $147$ = '$\Rightarrow n<147 $'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) says that there is some number with *some* divisor smaller than 147

b) is really weird ... It says that there is some number $x$ such that for every number $n$: $n$ is either smaller than $147$, or it is true that for all numbers $k$: $x=n\cdot k$. So note that if you pick some number $n \geq$ (say, $n=1785$) it must then be true that for all numbers $k$: $x=1785\cdot k$. That's a crazy claim: it would mean that $x=1785 \cdot 1   = 1785 \cdot 2 = 1783 \cdot 3 ...$ which is clearly false. But the claim you have to symbolize is clearly true: Sure, there is some number such that all of its divisors are smaller than $147$: this is clearly true for any number smaller than $147$. So, no, b) is not it either

c) is right: *If* $n$ is a divisor of $x$, then $n$ is smaller than $147$

d) is bad news: You have an existential in combination with a conditional, which is almost always a red flag, because you can always make a conditional trivially true by making its antecedent false. So it is here: Can you find some number $n$ such that if $x = n \cdot k$, then $n <147$?  Yes, exactly because you can simply pick $n > x$, in which case   $x = n \cdot k$ is false, and hence $x = n \cdot k \rightarrow n < 147$ is true.   But this is what is called a 'vacuous truth'... it does not make any interesting claim at all. It certainly does not end up saying that every divisor of $x$ has to be smaller than $147$

Comment: d)is really confusing me, so it is incorrect right

Comment: @Telaa Yeah, that one is confusing indeed... and indeed incorrect. Again, I can make d) vacuopusly true by picking, say, $x=1$ and $n=2$. Because then for any $k$ it will be false that $x = n \cdot k$, but therefore 'vacuously' true that $n <147$. So, like the claim given to you, claim d) is true, but it really does not end up making any claim about the divisors of $x$ at all

Answer (score 2):

The answer is c) because 'there is a natural number' = '$\exists x$', 'whose every divider' = '$\forall k,n\in\mathbb{N}, x=kn$' is smaller than $147$ = '$\Rightarrow n<147 $'